# How can I make a link in Markdown to display it correctly in docsify?

Tags: docsify

I'm create a Readme documentation using docsify. I use Markdown for it.
There's an issue with the link. I do this link in markdown as

```
https://its.1c.ru/db/edtdoc#content:76:hdoc
```

Screenshot for reference:
[image]

In docsify this looks as:

```
hdoc" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> with "Title" and 404 error.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example link to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Example [link](https://www.example.com/)

These examples show how it's done.

```markdown
[a link](https://www.example.com/)

[edtdoc](https://its.1c.ru/db/edtdoc#content:76:hdoc)
```